# Azure Application Insights Webhook Payload for Alerts

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

In Azure Application Insights Alerts we have configured Webhooks to send Json Payload to ServiceNow (third party ticket generation app). Alerts are fired and we can view that on Azure Portal but is there anyway to know what was the PAYLOAD that was sent at that specific time when the Alert was fired. I can see the history of the Alerts fired but there is no view/information on what was the payload that was generated and sent thru webhook.

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the alert's payload by running a query against the Alerts Management REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts/getbyid

If you're using the common alerts schema, the payload you'll get is exactly the one that was sent through the webhook. Otherwise, some fields might appear under the 'essentials' section instead of under the 'context' section.

Comment: Thank you will give it a try.